# Firebase function deploy error "Error: Refresh token must contain a "client_id" property."

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I tried deploying a Firebase function, but I got the following error.

> Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Refresh token must contain a "client_id" property.

The full terminal output after running deployment is like

```
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
⚠  functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions. Please upgrade using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.
⚠  functions: Please note that there will be breaking changes when you upgrade.
i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env.development.

Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Refresh token must contain a "client_id" property.
```

I'm using the following versions for firebase.

```
"firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.18.0",
```

The app initialization code looks like

```js
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();
```

Deployment was working about a month ago, so I cloned my git repo again. But, even trying to deploy the same code is giving me the error.

I have proper authentication on my CLI because when I run `firebase projects:list`, it shows me the correct list of projects, and `firebase use <PROJECT_NAME>` also works.

I also tried manually setting the firebase config in app initialization part by doing

```js
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: <VALUE_FROM_FIREBASE_CONSOLE>,
  authDomain: <VALUE_FROM_FIREBASE_CONSOLE>,
  projectId: <VALUE_FROM_FIREBASE_CONSOLE>,
  storageBucket: <VALUE_FROM_FIREBASE_CONSOLE>,
  messagingSenderId: <VALUE_FROM_FIREBASE_CONSOLE>,
  appId: <VALUE_FROM_FIREBASE_CONSOLE>
};
admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Comment: Have you reinstalled firebase? As per [this github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1703) it seems that there was a similar issue fixed in a version released 4 days ago. Perhaps try refreshing your install - I see you're a couple versions behind if you're using `V9.8.0`. Latest release is `V11.5.0`.

Comment: @JoeMoore Thanks so much! It worked for me. As a side note, I had to change the version of some typescript related dependencies as well as my firebase-tools to v11.18.0.

Comment: Perfect, I'll add it as an answer down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in `V11.5.0` released on the 19th of January 2023. After the bug was found and reported on [this Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1703).

Please reinstall/update Firebase to fix.

```
npm install firebase-admin@latest
```